# zipfile several passwords match

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have very strange behavior with `zipfile` class and I hope that someone can help me solve the problem that bothers me.

I wrote a short script which tries to open zip file encrypted by password (it was ziped by WinRar), but turned out that `zipfile` class does not rise an exception for several other passwords which are incorrect.

So my password for the zip file was 'evil' but `zFile.extractall` did not rise execpction when password was one of

- 'checkouts',
- 'disannuller',
- 'euornithes' or
- 'yamaltu'.

Additional content after extracting with `zipfile` class using any listed passwords were incorrect. Even WinRar does not allow unziping using those passwords.

My Python code is as follows:

```
import zipfile

diffrentPass = [
            'wrongpass1',
            'wrongpass2',
            'checkouts',
            'disannuller',
            'euornithes',
            'evil',
            'yamaltu']


def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print 'Fount password : ', password
    except:
        pass

def main():
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile("evil.zip")

    for password in diffrentPass:
        extractFile(zFile, password)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

UPDATE :

I know that i skipped exception, but please look on out from program :

```
wrongpass1 was incorrect
wrongpass2 was incorrect
Fount password :  checkouts
Fount password :  disannuller
Fount password :  euornithes
Fount password :  evil
Fount password :  yamaltu

Process finished with exit code 0
```

lines :

```
Fount password :  checkouts
Fount password :  disannuller
Fount password :  euornithes
Fount password :  yamaltu
```

should not appear at all

Adding for example :

```
def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print 'Fount password : ', password
    except Exception, e:
        print password + " was incorrect"
```

nothing changes in output

---

UPDATE + what happened

@Phil Frost [Explain what happened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14091768/1629506)

to be sure that it is actually the point of the my problem i add to scripts some debug prints to compare check_byte in password and file.

Example output :

```
#!! Wrong pass, check_byte are diffrent
#  raised RuntimeError("Bad password for file", name)
Checking bytes for :  wrongpass1
pass check_byte : 47
file check_byte  112
Pass is correct for zipfile class :  False

#!! wrong password but for zipFile is ok , check_byte are the same 
# but file will be the unpacked incorrectly
# RuntimeError("Bad password for file", name) will be not rise
Checking bytes for :  checkouts
pass check_byte : 112
file check_byte  112
Pass is correct for zipfile class :  True
Fount password :  checkouts

#!! password ok 
Checking bytes for :  evil
pass check_byte : 112
file check_byte  112
Pass is correct for zipfile class :  True
Fount password :  evil
```

Code :

```
import zipfile, zlib, binascii, struct
from zipfile import _ZipDecrypter

diffrentPass = [
    'wrongpass1',
    'wrongpass2',
    'checkouts',
    'disannuller',
    'euornithes',
    'evil',
    'yamaltu',
    'wrongpass1',]



def extractFile(zFile, password, bytes):


    print '\nChecking bytes for : ', password
    zd = _ZipDecrypter(password)
    h = map(zd, bytes[0:12])

    print 'pass check_byte :', ord(h[11])

    for item in zFile.infolist():
        if item.flag_bits & 0x8:
            check_byte = (item._raw_time >> 8) & 0xff
        else:
            check_byte = (item.CRC >> 24) & 0xff
        print 'file check_byte ',check_byte

    print "Pass is correct for zipfile class : " ,  ord(h[11]) == check_byte

    try:
        answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print 'Fount password : ', password
    except Exception, e:
        pass



def main():

    # begining of ziped file must be cut off  dummy method works ony on this specific zip file
    # ....20111126036.jpg
    bytes = open('evil.zip', 'rb').read(45+12)[-12:]

    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile("evil.zip")

    for password in diffrentPass:
        extractFile(zFile, password,bytes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: it does raise an exception you are just ignoring it with by calling pass

Comment: Make sure as Uku wrote to use (i think it would be) except NameError: and then do stuff instead of pass. An example could be: messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong password").

Comment: but if exepction is rised in line answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password) next line should not be executed...

Comment: I think you misunderstand except. Except is when the try: fails. So, you try if the password is correct in try, if its not the program will go to except.

Comment: Can you try using a *fresh* `zFile` each time? Maybe the class caches correct passwords? If you add `wrongpass1` to the end *again*, will it be reported as correct the second time?

Comment: @Dariusz looking on the print statements The correct password is `checkouts` i think, after valid password break the for loop to check next password. The file is already extracted so next passwords also getting valid somehow.

Comment: @Anony-MousseI added on list next wrong password and nothing has changed

Comment: @Aamir Adnan correct password is for sure evil ...

Comment: @Dariusz I have tested the code, even if i don't break the loop, the next password is printed as `incorrect password`. There is nothing wrong. It prints only a single password as valid which is `evil`

Comment: I have tested it on python 2.7.3 it works as expected the issue which you are facing was on 2.6 version. Don't know how many other versions of Python has this issue

Comment: hmm, please use print e, so when can see what's really going on, my code probably some other execption is occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the goal of this program is to brute-force the password out of a zip file. I'm guessing that you have a longer list of passwords that you have tried, and just the few listed in the question are not raising exceptions, while you have many more that behaved as expected.

It seems to me that as zipfile is implemented, you have a 1 in 255 chance of a password being accepted, and thus not raising an exception. This is because the password is validated by checking a 1-byte checksum:

```
if ord(h[11]) != check_byte:
    raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file", name)
```

([full source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py#l962))

Edit: after further research, this could be [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670831/python-problem-with-zipfile-library).

As far as I'm aware, zip encryption is weak and easily broken through means other than brute-force. However, I've never had a reason to do it myself and I don't know the particulars of what you are trying to accomplish, so I can't suggest a more specific solution.

Comment: you're right, I did it more for educational purposes than the specific use

Comment: i wrote some code that checks what you have explained (updated first post), and yes the way of checking pass by zipFile class is unreliable, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The exception is raised, but you are "swallowing it", because you do not show any error on it and just ignore it by calling "pass".

Also, there's another problem with your code, main module part is indented incorrectly.
In your current code the main() is never called because the call to the main module is part of the definition of main()

```
import zipfile

diffrentPass = [
            'wrongpass1',
            'wrongpass2',
            'checkouts',
            'disannuller',
            'euornithes',
            'evil',
            'yamaltu']


def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print 'Fount password : ', password
    except:
        print password + " was incorrect"


def main():
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile("evil.zip")

    for password in diffrentPass:
        extractFile(zFile, password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not ... I know that  out from this code...


    wrongpass1 was incorrect
    wrongpass2 was incorrect
    Fount password :  checkouts
    Fount password :  disannuller
    Fount password :  euornithes
    Fount password :  evil
    Fount password :  yamaltu

    Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: works fine for me apart from the fact that it should actually stop when it has found the correct one :)

Comment: @UkuLoskit of course you could stop when you found a matching password, but it shouldn't start reporting incorrect passwords after that either way.

Answer (score 0):

You have ignored the exception in your code. If you want it to raise exception, then:

```
def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print 'Fount password : ', password
    except Exception, e:
        # do something here before raising exception
        raise e
```

Or do not use `try` `except` block at all.

**Edit after comment**

If you want to report that password is wrong then you have to do that in `except` block, because when `zFile.extractall(pwd=password)` is executed exception is already thrown for the bad password, so the `print` will never executed.

```
def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print 'Password "%s" is correct' % password
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Password "%s" is incorrect' % password
        pass
```

Comment: The `print` will not execute when the excetion is originally thrown. What is wrong with not reporting the *expected* error?

Comment: There is something wrong with you last except. The except in your example will print 'fount password' when the password is inccorect?

Comment: @Evilunclebill I really don't know what does `Fount` mean I thought it is a word of another language. I have updated answer using English message.

Comment: I think its a bend version of "found" ;-)

Comment: @Dariusz can you put the `evil.zip` file some where e.g. in dropbox and share it so that we can execute your code on it and identify the issue. (If file is not private)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are explicitly discarding any exception that might be raised, here:

```
try:
    answer= zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
    print 'Fount password : ', password
except:
    pass
```

if zFile.extractall() raises an exception, then the `except:` block is executed. Your except block contains `pass`, which in python means "do nothing" or "no-op".

Comment: The `print` will not execute when the excetion is originally thrown. What is wrong with not reporting the *expected* error?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse good point. I realize now that the intent of the code must be to try many passwords and print the one that is correct. I'd suggest structuring the code differently to make that clear, but that would be getting off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
    print 'Fount password : ', password
except:
    pass
```

I removed the "answer =", it didn't make any sense.
Also if you want a way out of the exception handler loop you could do this:

```
def zipExit(password):
    print 'Password found: '+password
    exit(0)

def extractFile(zFile, password)
    try:    
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        zipExit(password)
    except:
        pass

def main():
    ....the rest of your code here.
```

And for a password cracker (if you're using linux, but I'm asuming not since you use winRar) you don't want to print failed attempts to the screen, that is why the exception handler passes instead of printing something. 
Because you could point the program to output into a file.

~/python zipcrack.py > cracked.password

something like this.